# Check if SqlParameter value is in range of it's target SQL column

Tags: sql-server, c#-3.0, sqlparameter

**tldnr;**

How should I check the bounds on my `SqlParameter` values before attempting to put them in the database?

**Longer version:**

So, I have these dynamically generated SQL statements where I pass in a bunch of `SqlParameter`s.

The way we declare `SqlParameter`s is just

```
new SqlParameter("fieldName", value)
```

and we let the runtime figure out what the dbtype is.

That said, occasionally the update / insert statement fails, and we'd like to determine which field is too big (since our server only tells us that a field update failed, not WHICH one), by doing bounds checking.  That is we can't put a two digit number in a column which only allows 1 digit ([say a decimal(1,0) for example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b4848/12).)

We have the schema of the columns in memory (information_schema.columns ftw), so we could just try to do bounds checking on the SqlParameter value, but since the value is an object and not even necessarily a numeric type, how should I check that a value is in the range?

Or am I making the problem too hard and instead should have supplied the precision and scale when constructing the SqlParameters to begin with?  Or even better, should we be using types that reflect what the columns in the database are?

**Update:**

Setting the precision / scale doesn't seem to have any consequence as seen [in this code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RDIaYM):

```
decimal d= 10.0M*(decimal)Math.Pow(10, 6);
SqlParameter p = new SqlParameter("someparam", SqlDbType.Decimal);
                    p.Precision = (byte)1;
                    p.Scale = (byte)0;
                    p.Value = d;

Console.WriteLine(p.SqlValue); // doesn't throw an error, i would think the sql value would be at most 10, not 10 million.
```

Comment: I see that you did the appropriate test as creating a SqlParameter without a delcared DbType is really not a good idea. However, you did not execute that via a SqlCommand. I bet there would be truncate, either silent or causing an exception, if you did the Execute.

Comment: @srutzky:  Yes, sorry if my question isn't really clear.  My update statement would go to the database and then it would fail, but it wouldn't tell me which parameter caused the failure.  My goal is just to identify the parameter that causes the failure, and I'm wondering what is the best way to do that.

Comment: Right. I think I got that part. What I was saying is, in your test where you say that adding an invalid value to the SqlParameter did not error since you saw it via `WriteLine`, I am asking specifically if you changed your code that does the ExecuteNonQuery/Reader to include the precision and scale. I wouldn't expect a SqlParam to validate until at least the `SqlCommand.Execute*` method is called. But I am also trying another way to see if it works.

Comment: I just realized that you are correct that the actual execution of the query with the parameters is affected by how the parameters are specified.  If you specify the precision and scale, it will throw an argument exception instead of a sqlexception, however it is still the same problem of identifying the problematic parameter.  Interestingly I also found out that 5.0M and 5M are not the same, even if Sql doesn't complain, the tdsparser does.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `SqlParameter` does not validate upon the `Value` property being set. And `DataColumn` does not allow for specifying either `Precision` or `Scale` so not terribly useful. However, there *is* a way:

1. Using the collection of schema info that you already have, dynamically create an array of `SqlMetaData` based on the size of the schema collection and populate it with the column name and size data:

   ```
   SqlMetaData[] _TempColumns = new SqlMetaData[_SchemaCollection.Count];

   loop-of-some-sort
   {
      switch (_SchemaCollection.DataType)
      {
         case "decimal":
            _TempColumns[_Index] = new SqlMetaData(
                        _SchemaCollection.Name,
                        SqlDbType.Decimal,
                        (byte)_SchemaCollection.Precision, 
                        (byte)_SchemaCollection.Scale
                     );
            break;
          case "others...."
      }
   }
   ```
2. Create a new `SqlDataRecord` using the `SqlMetaData[]` from step 1:

   ```
   SqlDataRecord _TempRow = new SqlDataRecord(_TempColumns);
   ```
3. loop through `_TempRow` calling the appropriate `Set` method for each position, in a try / catch:

   ```
   string _DataAintRight;

   try
   {
      _TempRow.SetDecimal(_Index, _SchemaCollection.Value);
   }
   catch
   {
     _DataAintRight = _SchemaCollection.Name;
     break;
   }
   ```

NOTES:

- This will only do the same validation that passing params to a proc would do. Meaning, it will silently truncate values that are too long, such as too many digits to the *right* of a decimal point, and a string that exceeds the max size.
- Fixed-length numeric types should already be in their equivalent .Net types (i.e. `SMALLINT` value in an `Int16` variable or property) and hence are already pre-verified. If this is indeed the case then there is no additional benefit from testing them. But if they currently reside in a more generic container (a larger Int type or even a string), then testing here is appropriate.
- If you need to know that a string will be truncated, then that has to be tested separately. At least not as `SqlMetaData`, but in the loop and switch, just test the length of the string in that case.
- Regardless of any of this testing stuff, it is best to *not* create parameters by having .Net guess the type via: `new SqlParameter("fieldName", value)` or even `_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue()`. So regarding the question of if you "should have supplied the precision and scale when constructing the SqlParameters to begin with", absolutely yes.

---

Another option (which I can elaborate on tomorrow when I will have time to update this) is to validate everything as if there were no built-in containers that are supposed to be reflections of the real database/provider datatypes. So, there are two main considerations that will drive the implementation:

- Is the source data currently strongly typed or is it all serialized as strings?

  and
- Is there a need to know if the value will be truncated (specifically in cases where the value would otherwise be silently truncated, not causing an error, which could lead to unexpected behavior). The issue here is that inserting data into a field in a table that exceeds the specified max length will cause a `string or binary data will be truncated` error. But when passing data to a parameter (i.e. not direct to a table) that data will be truncated *without* causing an error. Sometimes this is ok, but sometimes this can lead to a situation where an input parameter has been specified incorrectly (or was correct but then the field was expanded and the parameter was never updated to match the new length) and might be chopping off the ends of some values that goes undetected until a customer reports that "something doesn't look quite right on a report, and oh, by the way, this has been happening off and on for maybe four or five months now, but I have been really busy and kept forgetting to mention it, maybe it's been nine months, I can't remember, but yeah, something's wrong". I mean, how often do we test our code by passing in the max value for each parameter to make sure that the system can handle it?

**If the source data is in the appropriate .Net types:**

There are several that do not need to be checked since fixed-length numeric types are the same between .Net and SQL Server. The ones that are pre-validated simply by existing in their respective .Net types are:

- bool -> BIT
- byte -> TINYINT
- Int16 -> SMALLINT
- Int32 -> INT
- Int64 -> BIGINT
- Double -> FLOAT
- Single -> REAL
- Guid -> UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

There are some that need to be checked only for truncation (if that is a concern) as their values should always be in the same range as their SQL Server counterparts. Keep in mind that here we are talking about strict truncation when the values are passed to parameters of a smaller scale, *but* will actually round up (well, at 5) when inserted directly into a column having a smaller scale. For example, sending in a DateTime value that is accurate to 5 decimal places will truncate the 3 right-most numbers when passed to a parameter defined as DATETIME2(2).

- DateTimeOffset -> [DATETIMEOFFSET(0 - 7)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx)
- DateTime -> [DATETIME2(0 - 7)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677335.aspx)
- DateTime -> [DATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx) : 0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31 (no time)
- TimeSpan -> [TIME(0 - 7)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) : 00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999

There are some that need to be checked to make sure that they are not out of the valid range for the SQL Server datatype as out of range would cause an exception. They also possibly need to be checked for truncation (if that is a concern). Keep in mind that here we are talking about strict truncation when the values are passed to parameters of a smaller scale, *but* will actually round up (well, at 5) when inserted directly into a column having a smaller scale. For example, sending in a DateTime value will lose all seconds and fractional seconds when passed to a parameter defined as SMALLDATETIME.

- DateTime -> [DATETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx) : 1753-01-01 through 9999-12-31, 00:00:00.000 through 23:59:59.997
- DateTime -> [SMALLDATETIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182418.aspx) : 1900-01-01 through 2079-06-06, 00:00 through 23:59 (no seconds)
- Decimal -> [MONEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx) : -922,337,203,685,477.5808 to 922,337,203,685,477.5807
- Decimal -> [SMALLMONEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179882.aspx) : -214,748.3648 to 214,748.3647
- Decimal -> DECIMAL : range = -9[digits = (Precision - Scale)] to 9[digits = (Precision - Scale)], truncation depends on defined Scale

The following string types will silently truncate when passed to a parameter with a max length that is less than the length of their value, but will error with `String or binary data would be truncated` if directly inserted into a column with a max length that is less than the length of their value:

- byte[] -> BINARY
- byte[] -> VARBINARY
- string -> CHAR
- string -> VARCHAR
- string -> NCHAR
- string -> NVARCHAR

The following is tricky as the true validation requires knowing more the options it was created with in the database.

- string -> [XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187339.aspx) -- By default an XML field is untyped and is hence *very* lenient regarding "proper" XML syntax. However, that behavior can be altered by associating an [XML Schema Collection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176009.aspx) (1 or more XSDs) with the field for validation (see also: [Compare Typed XML to Untyped XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184277.aspx)). So true validation of an XML field would include getting that info, if it exists, and if so, checking against those XSDs. At the very least it should be well-formed XML (i.e. `'<b>'` will fail, but `'<b />'` will succeed).

For the above types, the pre-validated types can be ignored. The rest can be tested in a `switch(DestinationDataType)` structure:

- Types that need to be validated for ranges can be done as follows

  ```
  case "smalldatetime":
    if ((_Value < range_min) || (_Value > range_max))
    {
      _ThisValueSucks = true;
    }
    break;
  ```
- Numeric/DateTime truncation, if being tested for, might be best to do a ToString() and using `IndexOf(".")` for most, or `IndexOf(":00.0")` for DATE and SMALLDATETIME, to find the number of digits to the right of the decimal (or starting at the "seconds" for SMALLDATETIME)
- String truncation, if being tested for, is a simple matter of testing the length.
- Decimal range can be tested either numerically:

  ```
  if ((Math.Floor(_Value) < -999) || (Math.Floor(_Value) > 999))
  ```

  or:

  ```
  if (Math.Abs(Math.Floor(_Value)).ToString().Length <= DataTypeMaxSize)
  ```
- Xml

  - as XmlDocument is pre-validated outside of potential XSD validation associated with the XML field
  - as String could first be used to create an XmlDocument, which only leaves any potential XSD validation associated with the XML field

**If the source data is all string:**

Then they all need to be validated. For these you would first use `TryParse` methods associated to each type. Then you can apply the rules as noted above for each type.

Comment: Unfortunately in spite of what looks like a lot of work, this didn't work for me for a decimal. https://dotnetfiddle.net/WdcEq1 .  I see your second bullet mentions having the type match the column type already, but it looks like for decimals there is no such type.

Comment: @user420667 Well, works on my box ;-). That is weird. I tinkered with the dotnetfiddle but can't get it to fail, whereas I can't get it to not fail on my machine. I am using .Net 4.5 in VS 2012. It is a SQLCLR proc but that shouldn't matter since the error is: `SqlContext.Pipe.Send` happening in `...SqlDataRecord.SetDecimal(Int32 ordinal, Decimal value)`. I will post another idea. Oh, and my second bullet regarded fixed length numeric types: Int, Int64, Int16, byte.

Comment: Huh, how odd.  It didn't work for me either when i ran it as a unit test using .NET 3.5 and VS 2008, as a library-type project called from the NUnit executable.

Comment: @user420667 That is weird. I didn't think that the environment of running inside of SQL Server would change stuff on that level. Unless there is a compilation setting / flag / warning level / etc that is different? Either way, I updated my answer with additional thoughts.